# I want to send an email which resolves my login id to email id(ctrl + k in outlook)

Tags: c#, email

If I put my login ID in Outlook and try to resolve it using <kbd>ctrl+k</kbd>, it resolves the login and gives me the respective email ID.

Can I do the same thing programmatically? I tried to put my login id in `MailMessage.To.Add`, but it only accepts a proper email ID.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I've edited your question for clarity to help you get better answers. Please take note of my edits and employ them when asking additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipient.resolve.aspx):

```
var r = MailMessage.Recipients.Add(name);
r.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
r.Resolve();
```